# how to adjust the text in select automatically?

Tags: css

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgp8fx81/5/)

I  have some options in my select box you can see that ,now my question is the text in that option should automatically adjust with the width of the select how can I achieve that?can anybody help me for that?

```
<select>
    <option>Legal, Credits and Links</option>
    <option>External Resources</option>
    <option>Frameworks and Extensions</option>
    <option>Ajax Requests</option>
    <option>Fiddle Options</option>
</select>

select{
    border: 1px solid #111;
    background: #fff;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
     }
```

Thank you.

Comment: I need the exact width

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Do you want the width of the `<select>` box to always adjust to the width of the selected option text it shows?

Comment: when I select the framework option and when it will appear on the select box it should adjust with the width

Comment: no not width but the text .

Comment: I'm convinced this is not possible without Javascript.

Comment: What should happen with the text?

Comment: actually in fiddle if you have seen then if the text is longer than the width the full text is being not shown so what i need is when the text is larger the text should srink and adjust with the width itself so I can seee the full text.

Comment: @SandhyaGor You can do it with jquery using css it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
select{
  border: 1px solid #111;
  background: #fff;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I need the exact width

Answer (score 0):

set the width to `auto` in css.

```
width:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the width property from your css, then it will automatically adjust itself to it's max length, and you won't need to adjust it.

```
select{
  border: 1px solid #111;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgp8fx81/10/) here